# How Can I make all my website components appear at once (instead of in pieces)?

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple python web site using Google App Engine.  Currently, the page loads the forms/text first and then pictures second.  When they load, things move around a bit until the layout is fully loaded.

Is there a way to make the page appear only when all components have loaded instead of piece by piece?

Thanks.

Comment: i removed "app engine" from the title as this has nothing to do with app engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is a Python question per se; this happens in HTML unless you pre-specify the size of your images, ie

```
<img src='myimg.jpg' />
```

will cause the browser to redo the layout after the image loads, while

```
<img src='myimg.jpg' style='width:200px;height:150px' />
```

will not.